# Verify user device in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to verify user's device when he/she is trying to log in with his registered devices.

the username, password and the grant_type is sent using `x-www-form-urlencoded` the request is

```
grant_type=password&username=user1&password=123&device_id=123456789
```

the `devise_id` is alrady captured in the client and sent with reqest. how can i read the `device_id` value on the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method in the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` on the server

Comment: do you have access to `Google` here is a starting point for starters.. 
[How to get hte DeviceID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172516%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: i'm trying to read the value and check it inside the server

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is the context here? What kind of login are you talking about? OAuth?

Comment: yes, i'm using OAuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there is no way except sending `device_id` in header and read it like

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        String deviceId = context.OwinContext.Request.Headers.Get("device_id");

    }
```